# Starling tag needs disambiguation

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

The [starling](/questions/tagged/starling) tag is used for two different technologies:

- Ruby based persistent queue server.
  [Starling](http://rubyforge.org/projects/starling/) is a light-weight persistent queue server that speaks the MemCache protocol. It was built to drive Twitter's backend, and is in production across Twitter's cluster.
- ActionScript 3 library for hardware accelerated 2D graphics.
  [The Starling Framework](http://www.starling-framework.org/) is a pure ActionScript 3 library that mimics the conventional Flash display list architecture. In contrast to conventional display objects, however, all content is rendered directly by the GPU — providing a rendering performance unlike anything seen in the Flash Player before.

Source: tag wiki [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/117695) and [body](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/117694) suggestions.

As far as I can tell, only one of the 16 questions under this tag are for the ActionScript library. So I was thinking about leaving the [starling](/questions/tagged/starling) for just that, and creating a [starling-framework](/questions/tagged/starling-framework) for the ActionScript one.

Would this be ok? Anyone have a better tag name or a different way of going about this?
(I'd rather have the edit suggester get the deserved credit for creating the ActionScript-related tag, so maybe leaving him a comment to that effect would be best?)

<sub>I voted to reject the suggested edits since documenting a tag for two uses seems inappropriate to me. The tag currently has a dangling body and no excerpt as far as I can tell.</sub>

Comment: Well, Clarice, have the tags stopped screaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd split it in starling-server and starling-framework.

The starling framework is likely to get much traction quite soon (it's based on flash player 11, which only was released a couple of days ago). I don't see why either should be preferred over another.