# What's the purpose of meta's [posse] tag when [clean-up] already exists?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request

Recently people have started using the [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) tag. However the [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up) tag has been around much longer and serves mostly the same purpose. Half of the 12 questions with [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) are already tagged with [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up), and most of the others have the text "clean up" in their title or body.

It seems that [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) should just be made a synonym of [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up). Does anybody disagree?

Comment: [Posse] is inherently cooler.

Comment: Or just make a new tag called cleanup-posse. And set up the synonyms to that.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I'll concede that. :P I'd also be satisfied by making [meta-tag:clean-up] a synonym of [meta-tag:posse].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't deny that [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) is probably cooler. Its origins are from Programmers' efforts to gather a posse to help clean up a humongous fraction of their site.

Here, though, a lot of our cleanup jobs don't need a whole posse. [Some are just small jobs that a single individual could do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108817/starling-tag-needs-disambiguation), while [others are about the etiquette of cleanup jobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57333/is-it-better-to-remove-questions-which-are-useless-to-community). Really, the combined tag operates a lot like [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).

I've thus gone and merged them into [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up). The final name can be changed at any point, but I felt that the consolidation was important and we had no reason to continue with them separate.

Comment: Sorry to nag, but can we get a [status-completed] for this question?